# How to let users who have not signed up have full access to user profile and its links?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following in template

```
<div class="profile-navbar">
{% url 'users:profile' user.id as profile_link %}
<a class="item home" href="{{ profile_link }}">Home</a>

{% url 'users:profile_ask' user.id as profile_ask_link %}
<a class="item" href="{{ profile_ask_link }}" > Ask <span class="num">0</span></a>

{% url 'users:profile_answer' user.id  as profile_answer_link %}
<a class="item" href="{{ profile_answer_link }}" > Answer <span class="num">0</span></a>

</div>
```

The urls are

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<userid>\d+)', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'^profile/ask/(?P<userid>\d+)', views.profile_ask, name='profile_ask'),
url(r'^profile/answer/(?P<userid>\d+)', views.profile_answer, name='profile_answer'),
```

Here is the view function:

```
def profile(request,userid):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.user.id == userid:
            pass
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
         pass
    return render(request, template_name)
```

Guest visitors can visit the page if he/she types in the link but the links in the page (the above template) don't work. 
What's wrong that I'm doing here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your urls? You are naming them incorrectly.

Comment: @jape I've added the urls.

Comment: What are you expecting a user to *see* if they go to a profile page without logging in? How can an unregistered user have a profile?

Comment: I want guest visitors to be able to view registered users' profiles. Unregistered users do not have profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take two approaches at this (second is the preferred method):

1.)

```
<div class="profile-navbar">
    <a class="item home" href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}">Home</a>
    <a class="item" href="{% url 'profile_ask' user.id %}" > Ask <span class="num">0</span></a>
    <a class="item" href="{% url 'profile_answer' user.id %}" > Answer <span class="num">0</span></a>
</div>
```

2.)

**models.py:**

```
# Completely making this up, but you'll get the idea
class Model(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def get_profile_url(self):
        return reverse('profile',
                       kwargs={'userid': self.user.id})

    def get_profile_ask_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_ask',
                       kwargs={'userid': self.user.id})

    def get_profile_answer_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_answer',
                       kwargs={'userid': self.user.id})
```

**html:**

```
<a class="item home" href="{{ request.user.get_profile_url }}">Home</a>
<a class="item" href="{{ request.user.get_profile_ask_url }}"> Ask <span class="num">0</span></a>
<a class="item" href="{{ request.user.get_profile_answer_url }}"> Answer <span class="num">0</span></a>
```

-

The second method is preferred because it is now universal. If you need to make changes, you only need to do it in the model. If you set it up the first way I showed, you'll need to go through every single template and make the changes - pain in the butt.

I wanted to show you the first method so you can see what is happening, but I highly recommend following the format of the second one.

*Note: I typed this directly in the response, so make sure the syntax and variables are correct before using. You'll also need to change it based on your model, etc. Feel free to ask questions if you get stuck.*

**EDIT:**

Also, change your urls to this (should use a trailing slash and dollar sign):

```
# I'm assuming these are extended from a branch?
url(r'^profile/(?P<userid>\d+)/$', 'profile', name='profile'),
url(r'^profile/ask/(?P<userid>\d+)/$', 'profile_ask', name='profile_ask'),
url(r'^profile/answer/(?P<userid>\d+)/$', 'profile_answer', name='profile_answer'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def profile(request, userid):
    user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, id=userid)

    template_name = 'users/profile.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
         pass
    return render(request, template_name, {'user_profile': user_profile})
```

Comment: Thanks!  The first approach doesn't work. It gives an error. user.id doesn't exist if the user who's accessing the page isn't logged in.

Comment: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(None,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'accounts/profile/(?P<userid>\\d+)']

Comment: @Brian Are you trying to let anonymous users visit existing users' page? For example, Anonymous user wants to visit Brian's profile?

Comment: @Brian If yes to my comment above, can you please post your view, too? Also, take a look at my edit for changes to make to your `urls.py`.

Comment: yes, I want to make anyone on the web have access to a user's profile.  I've added the view function. It's not completed yet but it should not return an error ?

Comment: @Brian In my edit under `views.py`, you'll want to pass something like that for the user. Then in your template, do something like `{{ obj.get_profile_url }}`.